# Iframe embedding

Tags: iframe, site-settings

I am a site collection administrator. I can embed youtube videos in a page, but I am unable to embed an Excel file from the site Documents (or OneDrive). The error message I receive is:

> Embedding content from this website isn't allowed, but your admin can change this setting.

I do not see "HTML Field Security" option in the Site Collection Administration section, which means that scripting is disabled by the organization administrator, but wouldn't that disable embedding completely (even from youtube)?

Comment: Use the page viewer webpart and display the document. Will work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

To display Excel content in a SharePoint page, you should use the Excel Web Access Web Part. See the article [Display Excel content in an Excel Web Access Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-Excel-content-in-an-Excel-Web-Access-Web-Part-25d58766-b3fb-41a4-9c86-3e50dc28a5ef?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but we do not have the Enterprise version. We have Sharepoint as part of Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, which consists in using Power BI to host the report and then embed it from Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a HTML field security if you are admin. Have you checked this guide: http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/05/22/how-to-use-html-field-security-and-insert-iframes-into-sharepoint-2013-sites.aspx?